# how to upload a safari extension to app store

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, safari

This is my first time uploading anything to the apple store and i might be missing something because I am building a safari extension and while using `xcode` and after creating the archive, when i click on `upload to app store` i get the following error:

[image]

(My developer account is currently active and paid)

I read online that some configuration need to be done on the `profile` and `certificate`.

I created:

- a certificate but its not linked to my keychain on the computer (is this required?)
- an identifier and thats the one that i am using on xcode as bundle identifier.
- an app on `app store connect` with all the details needed for the extension.

is there something that i am missing in the process and if anyone is familiar with the error attached, how can i possibly upload my extension to the apple store?

Comment: In the signing and capabilities tab in Xcode make sure you have selected your paid team,  not your personal team.